# Which sentence reads better?

Tags: sentence-construction

1) I come from a loving and supportive family, **who are very important** to me.

or is is better to write:

2) I come from a loving and supportive family, **and they are very important** to me.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, as a native English speaker, the second sounds better and more correct, but I don't think one is wrong.